# how to query all current polkadot accounts with polkadot js?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I'm looking to query all Polkadot accounts and so I can sort them by balance. which javascript api should I use? I'm not just looking for accounts with identities. I'm looking for all accounts thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Polkadot JS: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/

To query all acccounts you need to look at all the entries of `system.account`

```js
let users = substrate.query.system.account.entries();
```

Then to look at the total balance of a particular user you need to look at their `data.free` and add that to their `data.reserved`.

Here is how you will get the data for the first user:

```
let account_id = util_crypto.encodeAddress(users[0][0].slice(-32));
let free_balance = users[0][1].data.free.toNumber();
let reserved_balance = users[0][1].data.reserved.toNumber();
```

From there, you should be able to figure out how to sort the list and create the output you want.

EDIT:

Here is a full script for others:

```js
var { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');
var { encodeAddress } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto')

async function main() {
    // Substrate node we are connected to and listening to remarks
    const provider = new WsProvider('ws://localhost:9944');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });

    // Get general information about the node we are connected to
    const [chain, nodeName, nodeVersion] = await Promise.all([
        api.rpc.system.chain(),
        api.rpc.system.name(),
        api.rpc.system.version()
    ]);
    console.log(
        `You are connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`
    );

    // Adjust how many accounts to query at once.
    let limit = 50;
    let result = [];
    let last_key = "";

    while (true) {
        let query = await api.query.system.account.entriesPaged({ args: [], pageSize: limit, startKey: last_key });

        if (query.length == 0) {
            break
        }

        for (const user of query) {
            let account_id = encodeAddress(user[0].slice(-32));
            let free_balance = user[1].data.free.toString();
            let reserved_balance = user[1].data.reserved.toString();
            result.push({ account_id, free_balance, reserved_balance });
            last_key = user[0];
        }
    }

    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: you are awesome thank you very much for this!!

Comment: needs a `const` before `user` at the for loop

Comment: Can you explain `user[0].slice(-32)`?  I believe `User[0]` is `StorageKey<[AccountId32]>` but I also don't understand what that means.  Is it an array of AccountId32?

Comment: Entries returns a list of storage keys, which is some hash plus the raw key of the user. That code takes only the last 32 bytes of the key, which is the 32 byte account id. If you run the script, you will see that `User[0]` is actually 80 bytes on Polkadot. See https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/

Comment: remember to npm i the requirements and run in terminal with node <file_name>. Also how do you get what web socket address the connected node is?

Comment: alternatively you can go to subscan and look at all of your accounts. then you will see all of your assets with no code!