# How do I get a list of all accounts in a Substrate based Parachain?

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I want to get a list of all accounts in a parachain. I am running a full node on the Kusama network. How do I get a list of all accounts in a parachain?

I tried reading a few documentation pages but all are focused on making transfers but none address where to view accounts from?

If there is no direct way, how do I keep a track of all transfers such that I know what addresses are in the parachain? Are transfers an `event` or `extrinsic`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to query all current polkadot accounts with polkadot js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228220/how-to-query-all-current-polkadot-accounts-with-polkadot-js)